# FluentAssertion fail to compare enumerable of strings

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, fluent-assertions

This code works fine

```
    [Test]
    public void boo()
    {
        var collection = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        collection.Should().Equal(1, 2, 3);
    }
```

But, this fails

```
    [Test]
    public void foo()
    {
        var collection = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        collection.Should().Equal("1", "2", "3");            
    }
```

The failure message is:

> 'Expected collection to be equal to {1} because 2, but {"1", "2", "3"}
>   contains 2 item(s) too many.'

What is wrong here? Why enumerable of string could not be compared?

And, of cause, my question is - how to handle case in foo() ?

Comment: does Equal() compare that it's the same instance or same value (not the same)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the compiler selects the wrong overload of Equals() because of limitations in C#. In your particular case, it's taking the Equals(string expected, string reason, params string[] args), instead of Equals(IEnumerable). I have never found an easy way to solve this ambiguity in FluentAssertions.

To solve your problem, wrap the expected values in an array.

```
[Test] 
public void foo()  
{ 
  var collection = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }; 
  collection.Should().Equal(new[] {"1", "2", "3"});              
}
```

Comment: "instead of Equals(IEnumerable)" is not correct. The OP was aiming to use `Equals(params object[])` (as in the first example), since has passed 3 parameters, not one `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the 2nd call is resolved to the following overload:

```
public AndConstraint<TAssertions> Equal(IEnumerable expected, 
                                        string reason, 
                                        params object[] reasonArgs);
```

Instead of:

```
public AndConstraint<TAssertions> Equal(params object[] elements);
```

To get the desired result you can force the compiler to the right overload method, for example by doing:

```
collection.Should().Equal((object)"1", "2", "3");
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens with the test of:

```
[Test]
public void foo()
{
    const string one = "1";
    const string two = "2";
    const string three = "3";
    var collection = new[] { one, two, three };
    collection.Should().Equal(one, two, three);            
}
```

I assume as Kenny acknowledged in a comment that you're doing reference equality where those strings are not the same reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try SequenceEquals instead?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx

And the Equals method is just comparing the references for equality.

Here's a line from a unit test in one of my projects:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(actual.OrderBy(x => x)));
```

All of the elements in "expected" and "actual" implement IEQuatable.